# Do you think Monero Payments are ok?

Tags: gpu-mining, transaction-confirmation, payment-id, cloud-mining

I'm not sure if a website that pays their users Monero can be trusted.

[Zagtor](https://zagtor.com) is mining different coins each time and paying daily their users according to the hashrate. As a fan of Monero, I think it is a good idea to get XMR, but how can they prove that the payments are made?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this reasoning is along the lines as saying:

I think my employer can't be trusted. I get paid, but they don't allow me to see my colleagues pay checks.

The important thing is to know is your hash rate. Try a few open source variants to get a base line average of your hashing power. Use available mining calculators such as [this one](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr?HashingPower=500&HashingUnit=H%2Fs&PowerConsumption=200&CostPerkWh=0.12) to know what you can expect. Depending on the payout scheme this may not always be accurate, but it is a start.

Lastly, read reviews on mining pools. Try some out for a week or two to see where you make the most coin.

They can certainly prove they paid you if you didn't receive the funds. [More info here](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/prove-payment)